# URL validation. ng-pattern not working

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, regex, validation

```js
$scope.regex = '^((http|https|ftp):\/\/)?([a-z]+\.)?[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z]{1,4}){1,2}(/.*\?.*)?$';

This is the regular expression i'm using to validate url, and its working fine. I have checked it on AngularJS website.
```

```html
<div class="field_input">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <input type="text" name="website" ng-model="custom.websites" placeholder="www.daiict.ac.in" ng-minlength=3 ng-pattern="regex" required/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="valid-chk" ng-show="requestForm1.website.$dirty" style="margin-top: 5px;">
  <i style="font-size: 1.15em;padding:0px;" ng-class="{'false':'icon-close', 'true': 'icon-correct'}[requestForm1.website.$valid]" class="icon-correct"></i>
</div>
```

This is html snippet where the i'm trying to validate the input field.
However this is not working. Also when I used ng-pattern all other validations on input field, except required, are also not working. Any idea why...

Comment: `$scope.regex = /^((https?|ftp):\/\/)?([a-z]+\.)?[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z]{1,4}){1,2}(/.*\?.*)?$/i;`

Comment: I have tried it. But still not working

Comment: It must be inside double quotes. If it does not, also try doubling backslashes: `$scope.regex = "/^((https?|ftp):\\/\\/)?([a-z]+\\.)?[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z]{1,4}){1,2}(\\/.*\\?.*)?$/i";` Also, call as `ng-pattern="{{regex}}"`

Comment: I have used double quotes.

Comment: Yeah it was solved. The problem was with ng-pattern="{{regex}}". I wasn't using curly braces. Thank you for quick help

Comment: should work for `ng-pattern="regex"` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Comment: Not sure. But it doesn't! @shaishabroy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `ng-pattern="regex"` contains a string `regex` as its value. In order to refer to the real variable `$scope.regex`, you need to use the template syntax:

```
ng-pattern="{{regex}}"
```

Also, since the pattern is defined using a *string* you need to double escape the backslashes (see [a similar example code at the *ngPattern* reference page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)):

```
$scope.regex = '^((https?|ftp)://)?([A-Za-z]+\\.)?[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}){1,2}(/.*\\?.*)?$';
```

Or just place them into a character class to avoid any ambiguity:

```
$scope.regex = '^((https?|ftp)://)?([a-z]+[.])?[a-z0-9-]+([.][a-z]{1,4}){1,2}(/.*[?].*)?$';
```

Or even pass the `RegExp` object since that way you can use the case-insensitive flag:

```
$scope.regex = "/^((https?|ftp):\\/\\/)?([a-z]+[.])?[a-z0-9-]+([.][a-z]{1,4}){1,2}(\\/.*[?].*)?$/i";
```

Alternatively, the same expression as above can be defined with a RegExp constructor:

```
$scope.regex = RegExp('^((https?|ftp)://)?([a-z]+[.])?[a-z0-9-]+([.][a-z]{1,4}){1,2}(/.*[?].*)?$', 'i');
```

I also suggest shortening `http|https` to `https?`.

Comment: Well, I guess I have finished editing the answer. Please check.

Comment: Is there a better regex that you can suggest?

Comment: I do not know what kind of requirements you have.  Perhaps, you can just replace `(/.*[?].*)?` with `/?.*` and use `([a-z]+[.])*` instead of `([a-z]+[.])?`. It seems to me that will match more URLs and will perform quicker.

Answer (score 1):

can try by using `new RegExp`

```
new RegExp(pattern, option)
```

I used `i` as option to ignore case

```
$scope.regex = $scope.regex = new RegExp('^((https?|ftp)://)?([a-z]+[.])?[a-z0-9-]+([.][a-z]{1,4}){1,2}(/.*[?].*)?$', 'i');
```

[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/B9J3eEu6peJLWKcA0ukE?p=preview)

Comment: Your pattern allows `wwwdialectcom` input.

Comment: in my example used @Dreamer pattern not mine