# Complete url validation angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to validate an url with angular.

I found this : [URL validation. ng-pattern not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602017/url-validation-ng-pattern-not-working)

So I used :

```
 ^((https?|ftp)://)?([A-Za-z]+\\.)?[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z]{1,4}){1,2}(/.*\\?.*)?$
```

It's work great for this exemple :

http://www.mywebsite.com

But it doesn't work for this complete kind of url :

http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/1